# Need to know what version of Selenium 3.x is stable

Tags: selenium

I'm still using selenium 2.53.0 (with Java) and I need to upgrade to a 3.x version. Can anyone tell me what a stable version of selenium 3.x would be? I'm hoping to avoid problematic or buggy versions, so that's why I'm asking people who have had experience with them.

Answer (score 1):

`3.141.59` is the currently latest stable version of Selenium `3.X`
You can always check that [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java):

Answer (score 0):

Each of the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) versions mentioned in [selenium/java/CHANGELOG](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG) were well-tested and were stable enough to be used for test execution.